# Image rollover after clicked (active)

Tags: css

I'm doing an image button rollover that has 3 stages (normal, hover, active).
I have the normal and hover stages working, however I can't seem to get the 'active' to work. That is, I want the image to stay on the active lever after it has been clicked.

Here is what I have:
http://jsfiddle.net/pufamuf/Q3YpU/1/

Thanks! :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do will require JavaScript. Your CSS is fine, but when the link is no longer active, the `:active` selector no longer applies, and there's not much you can do about that.

You could (for example) use JavaScript to respond to the click event by adding an extra CSS class to the tag, and use that class to style the link identically to your `:active` link. For example, if your JS adds the class "clicked", your rule might look like

```
#emailUs:active, #emailUs.clicked
{
  background-position: 0 -62px;
}
```

Many (most?) developers would probably use jQuery for something like this.

Answer (score 2):

The :active pseudo-class only applies while the element is in the process of becoming activated. Once the mouse click is released the element no longer falls under the :active category.

In order to produce your expected behavior you will need to use some Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery addClass on click event

Answer (score 1):

If you could use JavaScript, this would be simple. Come up with some class name (e.g., `active`), and add it to your `:active` declaration:

```
#emailUs:active, .active
{
    background-position: 0 -62px;
}
```

Then use JavaScript to listen for the `click` event on that link, prevent the default action, and add/remove the `active` class from the element as necessary.

However, if JavaScript *isn't* allowed, there's a much messier way to get what you want, which probably won't be feasible on a live site.

Change the link's `href` so that it points to itself:

```
<a id="emailUs" href="#emailUs" title="Email Us"></a>
```

Then use the `:target` selector in your CSS:

```
#emailUs:active, #emailUs:target
{
    background-position: 0 -62px;
}
```

Keep in mind that the second solution has some caveats that go with it:

1. It tries to reposition the page so that the link is at the top of the screen
2. There could be a bunch of issues if you're already using the fragment identifier on your site
3. It won't work at all in IE6-8

Comment: Thanks a lot sdleihssirhc :))